# How to animate div along path according to time of day

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, raphael, ellipse, angle

This problem has driven me nuts and I'm looking for insight into best way to solve this problem.

I have a div $(".sun") that I want to move along the circumference of an ellipse, which I've generated with Raphael.js, so that the ellipse is as wide as the screen and horizontally centered, and as tall as half of the width, and is absolutely positioned at 0,0 (top left):

```
//draw ellipse that is as wide as the window and half as tall as the width
var paper = Raphael(document.getElementById("ellipse"), Wwidth, halfIt);
var c = paper.ellipse(Wwidth/2, halfIt/2, Wwidth/2, halfIt/2);
c.attr({'fill': 'transparent', 'stroke': 'red'});
```

[jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/jelewis8/y47Cr/3/) (changed values in jsfiddle for demo)

The ellipse is a stylized representation of the path a celestial body travels in the sky. This means that at 6am, the sun is at the far left side of the screen at the ellipse's major axis. At 12noon the sun would be at the top center of the screen, and at 6pm the sun is on the far right of the ellipse's major axis.

Put in terms of degrees, 6AM = 180 degrees, 12 noon = 90 degrees, 3PM = 45 degrees, and so on. Essentially, each hour between 6am and 6pm is separated by 15 degrees. Add in a calculation for the minutes:

```
var hours = new Date().getHours();
(removed code that converts the numerical hour to my stylized degrees for brevity)
var mins = new Date().getMinutes();     
var minsdegree = mins * .25;    
var skyangle = hourdegree + minsdegree;
```

So for example, if it were 11:39AM, skyangle would equal 114.75 degrees.

*The Challenge:*
How can I animate the sun along the path of the ellipse such that it corresponds to my custom angle depending on the time. Technically, I don't need it to "animate" so much as simply correspond to the correct angle upon page load. However, it would be neat to have it animate along the path, if you kept the page open long enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/y47Cr/54/

updates every second.

Comment: Good try, but right now it's 10:27AM where I'm at. That means the sun should be at roughly 126 degrees (approximately where hour hand is on the clock). Your fiddle has the sun below the horizon line, which doesn't make sense.

Comment: sorry check the fiddle again, before it was exceeding the stack size.  I am just using your code for the position.  OK let me check it...

Comment: I'm still seeing the sun below the horizon line (middle of the ellipse).

Comment: OK check the latest update, I simplified your code, looks cool, ;-)

Comment: jeffrey, are you seeing the sun at the bottom of the ellipse or the top?

Comment: OK, i updated again..right now it is about 8 o'clock and i am seeing it to the bottom right. at midnight it should be directly at the bottom.  Is ti right?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14868/discussion-between-f8xmulder-and-jeffery-the-wind)

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to ignore your fiddle because it is inoperative.  Assume you have these variables:

- `cx`,`cy` -- the coordinates of the center of your ellipse;
- `rx`,`ry` -- the x and y radius of your ellipse;
- `skyangle` -- the current angle to be mapped onto the ellipse;
- `sun_width`, `sun_height` -- the width and height of the sun div.
- `sun_margin` -- a value, in pixels, for any additional gap you'd like to allow between the sun and the ellipse (at 0, the sun will be centered

You should be able to calculate where to position the sun using this javascript:

```
var sun_x = cx + Math.cos( Raphael.rad( skyangle ) ) * ( rx + sun_width + sun_margin );
var sun_y = cy + Math.sin( Raphael.rad( skyangle ) ) * ( ry + sun_height + sun_margin );
```

It's that simple.  However, I do believe jeffery_the_wind nailed it while I was pontificating.

Comment: jeffrey_the_wind's example isn't working per the requirements of the challenge. Giving your code a shot.

Comment: I think jeffrey_the_wind's approach is exactly what I am outlining -- I'd expect the same result.

Comment: jeffrey figured it out, and we've got ourselves a working model. Thanks for your input!

Comment: I love happy endings!  Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine your would want to use a sine function to solve for the coordinates. Since the x-axis is longer, you would want to run the x coordinates by some multiplier.

Heres an idea I came up with. It's been a while since math, so some of my terminology may be wrong.

```
var x, y, top, left,
    originX = 100,
    originY = 50,
    axisLengthX = originX*2,
    axisLengthY = originY*2,
    dist = Math.sin(deg) * axisLengthX,
    sunEle = document.getElementById("sun");

x = dist;
y = dist * (axisLengthX / axisLengthY); // relationship between X and Y axis length of ellipse

top = originY - y;
left = originX - x;

sunEle.style = "top: " + top + "; left:" + left;
```